# Android: Viewing pdf in Webview using GoogleDocs

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I am trying to open pdf links in my webview using Google Docs. The Webview initially accepts the url but in log cat i notice that at some point the url changes to "about:blank" and in the end it load only a blank page.

I have also overriden onPageStarted and onPageFinished methods and noticed that when shouldOvverideUrlLoading is called the second time by the WebView it changes the url to "about:blank"

Any thoughts on why this happens?

```
    @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(String url) {
    getView().loadWebview(url);
}

@Override
public void loadWebview(String url) {
    String pdfSuffix = ".pdf";
    String googleDocsUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + url;
    if (url.endsWith(pdfSuffix)) {
        Logger.i(LOG_TAG, "pdf loadwebview: url= " + googleDocsUrl);
        mView.loadUrl(googleDocsUrl);
    } else {
        Logger.i(LOG_TAG, "loadwebview: url= " + url);
        mView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```